# Kaniko fails to authenticate to docker hub registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, skaffold, kaniko

I am utilizing Kaniko with Skaffold, and I encounter a persistent issue when running skaffold dev. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "shubhamjr/brewapps:latest": POST https://index.docker.io/v2/shubhamjr/brewapps/blobs/uploads/: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:shubhamjr/brewapps Type:repository] map[Action:push Class: Name:shubhamjr/brewapps Type:repository]]
```

I have generated a secret and validated it twice; it appears to be correct. However, I consistently encounter this error. Below is my Skaffold configuration:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta18
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: shubhamjr/brewapps
      context: auth
      kaniko: {}
  cluster:
    pullSecretName: kaniko-secret
    pullSecretMountPath: /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    pullSecretPath: /kaniko/.docker/config.json
```

My objective is to have the image building process occur on my Amazon EKS cluster rather than on my local machine. I am using Skaffold to ensure that changes are reflected directly in my pod. The two Kubernetes contexts I am working with are the local Docker context and AWS EKS.

I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to achieving this goal.